# can't find mysqlbinlog in docker container [mysql/mysql-server:8.0.23]

Tags: mysql, docker

**step 1：create docker container**

```
docker run --name=mysql80 --restart on-failure -d -p3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test-2021 -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% -e TZ=Asia/Shanghai mysql/mysql-server:8.0.23 --lower-case-table-names=1 --bind-address=0.0.0.0 --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

**step 2：find mysqlbinlog**

I use `find / -name mysqlbinlog` command to find nothing in docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `mysql:8.0.23` image instead of the `mysql/mysql-server:8.0.23` image.
The `mysql` image also an official image.

> https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

Comment: Wow，Nice！I find it!

Answer (score 3):

For any MySQL tool, like `mysqlbinlog` or `mysqlimport` you must use the debian-based version, for example, 8.0.30-debian.

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/847

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
mysql/mysql-server:8.0.32
```

image.

The binary mysqldumplog is at /usr/bin/