# can not find mysqlbinlog command in docker?

Tags: mysql, docker

1. run mysql `docker run -d --name=mysql-server -p 3306:3306  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=t123456 mysql:8.0.30`
2. find command: `find / -name mysqlbinlog`,it only return one line:

```
sh-4.4# find / -name mysqlbinlog
find: '/proc/1/map_files': Permission denied
```

and run mysqlbinlog commmand failed:

```
sh-4.4# mysqlbinlog
sh: mysqlbinlog: command not found
```

--update--

i change version from 8.0.30 to 8.0.23 according to [can't find mysqlbinlog in docker container [mysql/mysql-server:8.0.23]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70223748/cant-find-mysqlbinlog-in-docker-container-mysql-mysql-server8-0-23) , and the command can be found , why is it missed in newer version?

Comment: You must use a debian based version  `8.0.30-debian` 
https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/847

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Available in latest debian version

```
  8.0.30-debian
```

Comment: why they remove this tool in some version?

Comment: I don't think this be the answer.